# AndroidViewClient- how to generate a double tap using culebra

Tags: android, python, androidviewclient

How to generate a double tap using culebra?

Unable to use:

```
vc.device.touch() twice (for double tap)
```

Also tried:

```
vc.device.longtouch(x,y)
```

Twice, did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are right, none of the workarounds work and it's very difficult to provide a generic solution, however you can do it for your specific device and here is how:

1. Start your app
2. Run `getevent` in `adb shell`
3. Double tap
4. Copy the events
5. Convert hex to dec
6. Send the same events using `self.device.shell('sendevent ...')`

May or may not work for your device.

Comment: Thank you!! It might actually work. but there are too many events for a single doubletap, so to convert hex to dec for each event maybe cumbersome :(

Comment: Python will do the conversion but be sure to add a `0x` in front of the hex numbers when you copy them.